# How to get overlapping objects in geodjango?

Tags: python, django, gis, postgis, geodjango

I'm creating an app using `geodjango`.
I have a model like so:

```
class WorldBorder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()
```

There can be 2 or more objects with overlapping borders in my database.

How can I determine if some objects have overlapping borders?
How can I get a queryset of objects with overlapping borders?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options, depending on what you want to achieve:

---

**Option 1:** You can use the [`__overlaps`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#overlaps) lookup:

Example of use:

```
an_mpoly = WorldBorder.objects.get(name='a_name').mpoly
overlapping_mpolys = WorldBorder.objects.filter(mpoly__overlaps=an_mpoly)
```

Now `overlapping_mpolys` is a queryset, containing every `WorldBorder` object who's `mpoly` overlaps with the `mpoly` of a `WorldBorder` object with `name='a_name'`.

---

**Option 2:**
If you need an `object to object` overlap check, you can utilize [GEOS API `overlaps`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.overlaps) method:

Example of use:

```
mpoly_1 = WorldBorder.objects.get(name='name_1').mpoly
mpoly_2 = WorldBorder.objects.get(name='name_2').mpoly

if mpoly_1.overlaps(mpoly_2):
    print("{} and {} are overlapping".format(mpoly_1, mpoly_2))
```

---